# GIMP plugin for rectifying scanned documents on Linux

Tags: images, image-processing, scanning, plug-in, gimp

I use (Devuan) GNU/Linux. I often scan official documents I receive, and want to store them. But the process of scanning (and sometime the original printing) distort the image relative to the original. To the extent that it's just uniform affine transformations like translation and rotation of the whole image - I fix that myself manually with GIMP. But when the distortion is non-uniform, I'm kind of at a loss.

A few years back I asked this question:

[Fix up scanned text documents as images](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27665/fix-up-scanned-text-documents-as-images)

but mostly got suggestions to write code with some template/sample scripts. I was hoping someone has implemented such functionality for GIMP, which is what I use for other aspects of the processing.

Obviously I'm looking for a FOSS plugin.